# FLASK how can I declare my db variable inside of the Flask.create_app function and import it into my other modules?

Tags: database, flask

Previously I declared my mysql.connector variable `db` outside of any function.

Hence I could import it into any module by simply using `from . import db`  .

However, now I have moved the declaration inside of the create_app function because I am working with different environments (development, production, testing) and hence the connection needs to be made inside the create_app(). This obviously puts `db` outside of scope and now I am no longer able to import it into my modules (primarily my blueprints)

```
def create_app(config_name):
    """
        PARAM
        config_name    'development', 'production', or 'testing'
    """

    instance_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'instance')
    # instance_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'instance')

    app = Flask(__name__, instance_path=instance_path)

    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    # app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'a7e6f8131a635119ca1ce2c82c7206e2c07072a9dd264189'

    if(config_name=='development'):
        database = "cbl_dev"
    elif(config_name=='production'):
        database = "cbl_prod"
    elif(config_name=='testing'):
        database = "cbl_test"
    else:
        print("Invalid value: '{}' provided for env variable FLASK_CONFIG".format(config_name))

    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="12345678",
        database=database
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make `db` in the global scope by `global db` inside the `create_app` function as follows:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    """
        PARAM
        config_name    'development', 'production', or 'testing'
    """
    
    global db

    '''
    rest of your code
    '''
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="12345678",
        database=database
    )
```

then, suppose you put `create_app` function in the file `Definitions.py`, so
and wherever you need to use `db` import it from `Definitions` as follows:

```
from Definitions import db
```

and use `db` as usual

Comment: is this method recommended?

Comment: @MuhammedJaseem is there other method to compare with?

Comment: Nour-Allah Hussein Not sure. I just asked because i have heard that using global variables is not recommended. Iam prolly wrong though.